# identifying numbering system / sequence / pattern in a bunch of strings in java

Tags: java, string

I have a bunch of strings like these

```
1. INTRODUCTION
2. BASICS
3. ADVANCED CONCEPTS
4. EXAMPLES
```

Each line above is a separate string. The same string can appear as follows-

```
A. INTRODUCTION
B. BASICS
C. ..
```

OR as

```
I) INTRODUCTION
II) BASICS
III) ...
```

OR as

```
10.01 INTRODUCTION
10.02 BASICS
...
```

So, I am trying to identify (and potentially eliminate) the sequence of any type (numbers, floats, roman numerals and totally unknown types) exits between these strings. 
What is the best way to do this in java?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: There is scanner class which can be helpful for you, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: You want to parse these strings but I don't understand what you want to do exactly, provide an input/output example.

Comment: ok, I think I should explained this better. imagine taking any word document that was created for any purpose, and consider ordered lists (except for the ones with graphics/bullets). There are so many variations that you could get. (1), a., i], 1.2.3, and so on. My attempt is to build something that recognizes this ordering for numbers, alphabets, numerals.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to split on the middle space?

```
public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String[] strings = new String[] {
                "1. INTRODUCTION",
                "2. BASICS",
                "3. ADVANCED CONCEPTS",
                "4. EXAMPLES"};

        for(String string : strings) {
            String[] tokens = string.split(" ");
            System.out.println("[" + string + "][" + tokens[0] + "][" + tokens[1] + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
[1. INTRODUCTION][1.][INTRODUCTION]
[2. BASICS][2.][BASICS]
[3. ADVANCED CONCEPTS][3.][ADVANCED]
[4. EXAMPLES][4.][EXAMPLES]
```

If you know your patterns use a simple design pattern like this

```
public class TestApp {

  private static IPatternStripper[] STRIPPERS = new IPatternStripper[] {
    new NumeralStripper()
    // more types here ...
  };

  public static void main(String[] args)  {

    String[] strings = new String[] {
        "1. INTRODUCTION",
        "2. BASICS",
        "3. ADVANCED CONCEPTS",
            "4. EXAMPLES"};

    for(String string : strings) {
      IPatternStripper foundStripper = null;
      for(IPatternStripper stripper : STRIPPERS) {
        if(stripper.isPatternApplicable(string)) {
          foundStripper = stripper;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(foundStripper != null) {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS: " + foundStripper.stripPattern(string));
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("ERROR: NO STRIPPER CAN PROCESS: " + string);
      }
    }
  }
}

interface IPatternStripper {  
  public boolean isPatternApplicable(String line);  
  public String stripPattern(String line);
}

class NumeralStripper implements IPatternStripper {

  @Override
  public boolean isPatternApplicable(String line) {
    boolean result = false;

    // code here checks whether this stripper is appropriate    
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public String stripPattern(String line) {
    String value = line;
    // code here to do your stripping
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not necessary that a space exists.

Comment: do you know your ordering pattern?

Comment: I am trying to process hundreds of documents which could have any pattern. But the normal patterns are those that I listed above. There are scenarios like 1)INTRODUCTION or (A)INTRODUCTION or i.INTRODUCTION. So many orderings/variations even when you stick to numerals, numbers and alphabets.

Comment: The approach I have given you is perfect for your needs as you can try all known combinations first and allow the program to crash or reject the string when it cant find an appropriate stripper, in which case you can either develop a new class or do it manually

Comment: you can even use an 'AbstractStripper' class that implements 'IPatterStripper' to do any shared logic duties and have all your sub-types extend it

Comment: your approach is more from a design perspective. I am looking for a solution to the problem, meaning, what is the best way to detect these varying patterns.